# How to switch frames using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I know this has been asked multiple times, and the suggested solution has been to use something like `browser.driver.switchTo('your-frame-name')` but I can't seem to access the same switchTo() method in my code.

This is my test :

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import {browser, by, element} from 'protractor';

describe('angular-test App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    browser.driver.switchToParentFrame()

    //expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
    expect(element(by.id('myHeader')).getText()).toEqual('Welcome to Angular Test App!  ');
  });
});
```

`switchToParentFrame()` is the only available method I get after the browser.driver.

This is how my HTML looks like

[image]

Any help is appreaciated, sorry for the vague description of the question but I'm pretty new to coding/protractor e2e testing.

Comment: A good start would be to have a look at the API: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor: Testing Angular App in an Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425909/protractor-testing-angular-app-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of protractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe')).getWebElement());
```

Comment: Apparently my IDE was not recognizing switchTo() method

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = element(by.xpath('iframe element')); // .//div[contains(@id,\'cke\')]/iframe   
browser.sleep(3000);
elem.click();    
browser.switchTo().frame(elem.getWebElement());    
browser.sleep(3000);    
element(by.tagName('body')).sendKeys('test');     
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();    
browser.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Why is there a browser.sleep(3000)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 browser.switchTo().activeElement();
```

or try to experiment with other available methods