# How to find dynamic XPath in angular popup modal?

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, xpath, protractor

When i try to write XPath then sequence is breaking from `ifame/#document/html`. I want to reach the yellow highlighted line starting from `div[@id='zdaasmodalbody']` i tried with, switchto window/frame but nothing works.

[image: Please click to see the image]

I tried this code but tool does not locate the element to identify its XPath:

```
cClickWait("/html/body/app-root/app-nav-menu/nav/a", "XPath");
```

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question, unless you edit it and I dont want to click on links to see the image, post it on the question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: I am unable to post the image in the question, i am a new user so stackoverflow does not allow me.

Comment: Welcome! Please post (copy/paste) the **actual** code into the question body so we can see it. A link to an image is not very helpful.

Comment: not a full answer but an idea where to look - you need to switch to that iframe first like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425909/protractor-testing-angular-app-in-an-iframe

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Thank you so much, yes i followed the link and find my solution there.

Answer (score 0):

You use below Xpath

```
//div[@id='zdaasmodalbody']//iframe[@class='ng-scope']
```

OR

```
//iframe[@class='ng-scope']
```

OR

```
//iframe[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@src,'https://')]
```

You need to switch to frame first as below before doing operation of its child elements

You can switch like:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='zdaasmodalbody']//iframe[@class='ng-scope']")));
```